# SingleOrDefault does not return current database content

Tags: ef-code-first

We are using Entity Framework 4.31 code first to handle crud operations against our sql server 2008 database.

1) I make a call to the db to pull back data ...

T _return1 = _dbset.Where(o => !o.F_isdeleted && o.I_id == id).Single();

2) i change the data in _return1 ...

3) i then manually make an update to this same record on the database using sql server management studio ...

4) i then make the same call found in 1 (into a 2nd object )to pull back the data, watching the call in sql server profile being made to the db.

T _return2 = _dbset.Where(o => !o.F_isdeleted && o.I_id == id).Single();

5) when i examine the contents of return2 i can see it does NOT contain the updated data from the database even though I can see the call being made to the db in 4.

Am i missing something here ??? 
why am i not seeing the current db contents in _return2, but seeing identical content to 
_return1 ???

Comment: Are you sure you're committing the change in Management Studio?  If you're not, this could explain why you're not seeing the results in another session. This behavior could also be caused by the isolation level your EF client is using.  I believe the default "read committed" allows non-repeatable reads, but perhaps you're using a different level?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exact problem you are having, but the best way to troubleshoot is to first see what SQL entity framework is generating when you are calling your database. You can either do it manually, use LinqPad or install something like http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/